# Angle between two vectors in the interval [0,360]

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the angle between two vectors.
Following is the code that I use to evaluate the angle between vectors `ba` and `bc`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

a = np.array([6,0])
b = np.array([0,0])
c = np.array([1,1])

ba = a - b
bc = c - b

cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (la.norm(ba) * la.norm(bc))
angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)

print (np.degrees(angle))
```

My question is,
here in this code:
for both `c = np.array([1,1])` and `c = np.array([1,-1])`  you get 45 degrees as the answer. I can understand this in a mathematical viewpoint because, from the dot product you always focus on the angle in the interval `[0,180]`.

But geometrically this is misleading as the point `c` is in two different locations for `[1,1]` and `[1,-1]`.
So is there a way that I can get the angle in the interval `[0,360]`   for a general starting point
`b = np.array([x,y])`

Appreciate your help

Comment: This is a geometry question, not Python or NumPy.  Even more, this is a question for direct research, not Stack Overflow.  You did not include the logic to differentiate `arccos` results with respect to the input values.  You simply have to look up the full-circle definitions and apply that logic, testing the `y` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, obtaining the angle between two vectors using the dot product is perfectly alright. However, since the angle between two vectors is invariant upon translation/rotation of the coordinate system, we can find the angle subtended by each vector to the positive direction of the x-axis and subtract one value from the other.

The advantage is, we'll use `np.arctan2`to find the angles, which returns angles in the range [-π,π] and hence you get an idea of the quadrant your vector lies in.

```
# Syntax: np.arctan2(y, x) - put the y value first!
# Instead of explicitly referring by indices, you can unpack each vector in reverse, like so:
# np.arctan2(*bc[::-1])

angle = np.arctan2(bc[1], bc[0]) - np.arctan2(ba[1], ba[0])
```

Which you can then appropriately transform to get a value within [0, 2π].

Comment: `np.arctan2(*bc)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have a small doubt.. in here for the arctan.. may I know why did you subtract the angle of `bc` from `ba` but not the other way(that is the angle of `ba`-`bc`)

Comment: @gune It's a matter of choice. If you do the opposite, you'd get the negative of the angle I'd get. Mathematically, this would correspond to *clockwise* and *anti-clockwise* rotations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me alot!